# Java Classes To C# Classes

Tags: c#, java

If I got a Java class in compiled format, is there a tool that can convert the class for me into a C# class? e.g. take the class, interface, enum etc and write it in C# with the same method signatures, same OOP inheritance etc. Just leave the gabs open for me to complete the implementation.

Answer (score 2):

[IKVM.NET Bytecode Compiler (ikvmc.exe)](http://www.ikvm.net/userguide/ikvmc.html):

> The ikvmc tool converts Java bytecode
>   to .NET dll's and exe's